# How to run a Bayesian meta-analysis with few studies

Tags: random-forest, bayesian, meta-analysis, forest-plots

I want to run a Bayesian meta-analysis with 3 studies in R:

`````
events_treatment <- c(41, 1, 3)
trials_treatment <- c(42, 2, 7) 
events_control <- c(126, 8, 2) 
trials_control <- c(166, 12, 7) ````
How can I do it using the bayesmeta () function in R?
Thanks!

I am expecting to have a OR (95% CI) of each study as well as the pooled OR (95% CI) of all them, and heterogeneity, and the forest plot. I appreciate to see this in Bayesian meta-analysis model using R codes. Thanks!
`````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.